# A better way to "Clear" all tables using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Hi currently when I want to clear my tables I use brute force:

```
        inventario_dboEntities inv = new inventario_dboEntities();            

        foreach (var item in inv.espiromex_dampers)
        {
            inv.DeleteObject(item);
        }
        foreach (var item in inv.espiromex_detalles)
        {
            inv.DeleteObject(item);
        }
        foreach (var item in inv.espiromex_docs)
        {
            inv.DeleteObject(item);
        }
```

I am sure there must be a better more elegant way to do this... how you guys do this kind of task?

Comment: Why do you need to clear the database? Couldn't you just send an SQL query?

Comment: this is my test database so I clear it time to time to start fresh!!!
yes I could send a query to truncate everything but I want to know if there is a way better than this using entity framework.

Comment: There isn't really a better way... I'd create some sort of 'ResetDatabase' storedprocedure that resets the tables (identities etc). Be sure to remove it during prod of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way and best practice is to truncate them in your query browser (since you are using MySQL) or as @TheCloudlessSky said using a stored procedure.

Also (but I am not sure) you could use Reflection and some fancy stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Another option you have in Entity Framework is to use ExecuteStorecommand do this
db.ExecuteStoreCommand(@"delete table1;delete table2;delete table3;");

Answer (score 2):

We do it by restoring a "baseline" DB from backup.